# Obtener URL de enclosure en RSS con PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

Leo un RSS con PHP, obtengo todos sus datos, excepto la imagen, que está dentro de un enclosure (url).
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$rss_todo = "url_del_rss";
$num_entrada = 1;
$max_entradas = 10;

$entradas = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($rss_todo));
echo "<br><center><h1>{$entradas->channel->title}</h1></center>";

foreach($entradas->channel->item as $entrada){ 
    $fecha = date("d/m/Y - H:i", strtotime($entrada->pubDate));
    $url_imagen = $entrada->enclosure->url;
    ?>
    <article>
        <h5><a href="<?php echo $entrada->link; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $entrada->title; ?></a></h5>
        <img src="<?php echo $url_imagen; ?>">
        <br>
        <?php echo $fecha; ?>
        <?php echo $entrada->description; ?>
    </article>
    <?php $num_entrada++; 
    if($num_entrada > $max_entradas){
        break;
    }
}
```

El formato del rss es el siguiente:

```
    <channel>
       <title>
          <![CDATA[ CANAL ]]>
       </title>
       <link>LINK CANAL</link>
       <description>
          <![CDATA[ DESCRIPCIÓN CANAL ]]>
       </description>
       <language>es-es</language>
       <pubDate>Mon, 27 Jul 2020 15:47:39 +0000</pubDate>
       <item>
          <title>
             <![CDATA[ TITULO ITEM ]]>
          </title>
          <link>LINK ITEM</link>
          <description>
             <![CDATA[ DESCRIPCIÓN ITEM ]]>
          </description>
          <pubDate>Sun, 26 Jul 2020 17:25:20 +0000</pubDate>
          <enclosure url="URL_IMAGEN.jpg" length="1" type="image/jpeg"/>
       </item>
   </channel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando de acceder a un elemento inexistente de *enclosure*

```
$url_imagen = $entrada->enclosure->url;
```

Con esa línea, el XML debería ser algo como

```
<enclosure>
   <url>url_de_imagen.jpg</url>
</enclosure>
```

En su lugar, debes buscar por atributo, que se guarda como arreglo del elemento, de esta línea del XML:

```
<enclosure url="URL_IMAGEN.jpg" length="1" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

Puedes acceder a propiedades *url*, *length* y *type*:

```
$url_imagen = $entrada->enclosure['url'];
$tipo_imagen = $entrada->enclosure['type'];
```

Referencia [SimpleXML - Ejemplo #5 Utilizar atributos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6565)

Prueba de funcionamiento con tus datos de ejemplo:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<EOT
<xml>
    <channel>
       <title>
          <![CDATA[ CANAL ]]>
       </title>
       <link>LINK CANAL</link>
       <description>
          <![CDATA[ DESCRIPCIÓN CANAL ]]>
       </description>
       <language>es-es</language>
       <pubDate>Mon, 27 Jul 2020 15:47:39 +0000</pubDate>
       <item>
          <title>
             <![CDATA[ TITULO ITEM ]]>
          </title>
          <link>LINK ITEM</link>
          <description>
             <![CDATA[ DESCRIPCIÓN ITEM ]]>
          </description>
          <pubDate>Sun, 26 Jul 2020 17:25:20 +0000</pubDate>
          <enclosure url="URL_IMAGEN.jpg" length="1" type="image/jpeg"/>
       </item>
   </channel>
</xml>
EOT;

$entradas = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($entradas->channel->item->enclosure['url']);
echo $entradas->channel->item->enclosure['url'];
```

> **Resultado:**
> `object(SimpleXMLElement)[2] public 0 => string 'URL_IMAGEN.jpg' (length=14)`
> `URL_IMAGEN.jpg`

Comment: Probado y nada, en el inspector de Chrome me muestra <img src(unknown)>

Comment: @Juanjo, acabo de editar la respuesta con prueba local y funciona sin problema.

Comment: Yo poniendo lo mismo pero con la url del rss, me devuelve "NULL".
Sin embargo, si pongo tu código me devuelve "object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { [0]=> string(14) "URL_IMAGEN.jpg" } URL_IMAGEN.jpg"

¿Puede ser que el rss bloquee de alguna manera el enclosure?

Comment: Edita la pregunta para poner un ejemplo de cómo recibes realmente el XML, probablemente falta una etiqueta; si te fijas en la respuesta, agregué `<xml>` al inicio y `</xml>` al final del código.